Why use a Hermite basis for natural cubic splines?
I understand at a basic level that the Hermite basis provides a more intuitive way to interpret the coefficients as the values and first derivatives at the endpoints of the piecewise functions. However, I don't entirely understand if this is a nice effect or a reason for why they're so popular in the first place. For a natural cubic spline, you don't know necessarily the first derivative but would be solving for it given $C^2$ continuity. So in this case, what makes Hermite splines better than just using the "standard" basis functions $\{1, t, t^2, t^3\}$?

Constructing a (cubic) spline typically involves solving a system of linear equations that enforce continuity between segments. If you express each segment in the power basis $\{1,t,t^2, t^3\}$, then you need equations to enforce continuity of position and first and second derivatives at each joint. So, with $n$ joints, you get roughly $3n$ equations. If you express each segment in Hermite form, you can share positions and first derivatives at the joints, so you only need equations to enforce continuity of second derivatives. So, with $n$ joints, you only need $n$ equations.
In short, using the Hermite form reduces the number of independent variables, and the size of the linear system you have to solve.

Thank you. And just to clarify, is this to reduce the size of matrix $A$ in solving $Ax=b$? It seems like here with the power basis we were able to simplify to have n rows in our system… https://people.clas.ufl.edu/kees/files/CubicSplines.pdf

I suppose this relies on the boundary conditions but then this comes back to the question of the usefulness in the case of NCS…

Yes, the linear system I was talking about is the $Ax=b$ one. With a bit of algebra, you can eliminate some of the variables in the power basis approach, and still end up with only $n$ equations. But the class notes skip a lot if the steps that are involved. If you use the Hermite basis, things are a lot more direct and obvious.

Assuming you are solving the fully worked out form where it’s a system of $n$ equations, is the only benefit of the Hermite basis then just more direct intuition of the coefficients? i.e. is there any reason to use it vs the power basis in an application?

A general disadvantage of the power basis is that it doesn’t directly use the geometric information that you probably care about (points and derivatives), so these must be computed, which risks floating-point errors. The Bézier-Bernstein basis is regarded as superior in this respect (see papers by Farouki and Rajan).
